# d3 transition not following path

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I like to make the aircraft follow the path. But whatever I have tried there is a shift between the transition path and the actual drawn path on the screen. Please look at the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghostman/Lhwz5vvt/)

```
d3.selectAll('.aircraft').transition()
.duration(7500)
.attrTween('transform', translateAlong(d3.select('#samplePath').node()))

function translateAlong(path) {
    let l = path.getTotalLength()
        // debugger
        return function (i) {
        return function (t) {
            let p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l)
                console.log(p.x, p.y)
                return 'matrix(-0.359863 -0.230143 0.230143 -0.359863' + p.x + ' ' + p.y + ')'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a space after the second `-0.359863` in the matrix definition:

```
return 'matrix(-0.359863 -0.230143 0.230143 -0.359863 ' +  p.x + ' ' + p.y + ')'
```